# Putting "$\forall y(y \in x \to \exists A \in F(y \in A))$" into words

Tags: proof-writing, definition

I'm new to mathematical proof and I struggle sometimes with putting definitions into words. If I had one like this:

$$\forall y(y \in x \to \exists A \in F(y \in A))$$

Would it be correct to read this as follows?

> For all y such that if y is an element of x, then there exists a set A in a family of sets F such that y is an element of A.

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: This is correct, but I find the first "such that" a little cumbersome; in natural language, it would be more common to say: "For all $y$; if $y$ is in $x$, then there is an $A$ in $F$ such that $y$ is (also) in $A$". Alternatively, you could say "for all $y$ such that $y$ is in $x$, there exists an $A$ in $F$ for which/such that $y$ is in $A$". ("for which" would be a style issue so you do not repeat "such that" too much, which makes parsing when hearing difficult). Note how this phrasing moves the premise to the quantifier, which you sometimes see in informal formulas.

Comment: "If $y$ is an element of $x$, then $y$ is an element of some set in the family of sets $F$."

Or more succinctly: "Each element of $x$ lies in some set in $F$.

Comment: I'd suggest to make clearer that the existential assertion occurs in the consequent, hence, it is conditioned on the antecedent, according to the formula *by itself*. So, more natural readings can be: For all $y$, whenever $y$ is in $x$, there exists a set $A$ in the codomain of $F(y)$ such that $y$ is in $A$ —if we take $F(y \in A)$ an abbreviated notation for function; or, for all $y$, whenever $y$ is in $x$, there exists a set $A$ in the family $F$ of sets $y$ such that $y$ is an element of $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare:

- For each ball *such that* *if* it is green, *then* it is heavy.   
   (incoherent)
- For each ball *such that* *if* it is green, it is heavy.   
   (incoherent)
- For each ball, if it is green, then it is heavy.     (OK)
- For each ball, if it is green, it is heavy.     (OK)
- For each ball such that it is green, it is heavy.     (OK)
- For each ball that is green, it is heavy.     (better)
- For each green ball, it is heavy.     (even better)
- Every green ball is heavy.     (best)

Viewing the first bullet point as a chopped-off sentence, adding parentheses to clarify its structure, and completing it:

- For each ball such that (if it is green, then it is heavy), it is smooth.
    (now coherent)

> $$\forall y\,\big(y \in x \to \exists A {\in} F\,(y \in A)\big)$$
>
> Would it be correct to read this as follows?
>
> > For all $y$ such that if $y$ is an element of $x,$ then there exists a set $A$ in a family of sets $F$ such that y is an element of $A.$

As illustrated above, your suggested reading becomes grammatical once “if...then” or “such that” is dropped. Let's correct it by replacing “such that” with a comma:

- For all $y,$ if $y$ is an element of $x,$ then there exists a set $A$
  in a family of sets $F$ such that $y$ is an element of $A.$

This literal reading can be condensed in several ways, the most succinctly as suggested by Pilcrow:

- Each element of $\color{red}x$ lies in some set in $\color{green}F.$

Abbreviating and rewriting the given formula: $$∀y{\in}\color{red}x\;∃A{\in}\color{green}F\;y\in A\\∀p{\in}\color{red}x\;∃q{\in}\color{green}F\;p\in q.$$

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, “such that” here is completely incorrect, not just unclear. The symbolic statement claims that the implication is true for ALL $y$, whereas your statement instead defines (basically) a subset of all $y$ for which the implication is true (it’s very weird to do this without following it up with a statement about that set).

It might be easier to see with the following statements:

“For all $x$, if $x$ is an integer, then $1/x$ is an integer.”

“For all $x$ such that if $x$ is an integer, then $1/x$ is an integer...”

The first statement is just false, but the second statement is equivalent to “For all $x$ such that $x=1$ or $x$ is not an integer...”

Even if this had been logically correct, having an implication after a such that statement is generally grammatically unclear. You’re better off rephrasing it without one or the other. Following from the previous example, you could instead say

“For all $x$ such that $x$ is not an integer or $1/x$ is an integer...”

or even better

“If $x$ is not an integer or $1/x$ is an integer, then...”